# How to calculate cashback value using .reduce() method from input value?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a form where the user can enter the name of the purchase and its value. With each addition, the cashback costs should be calculated automatically (via reduce method). Cashback is 0.5%. All purchases must be contained in the purchases array and have exactly three properties:

1. id - number
2. name - string (name of Purchase)
3. price - number (price of Purchase)

I can't seem to figure out how to use reduce method to calculate cashback value. Besides each cashback value, total cashback should be displayed as well.

```js
   let nextId = 1;

   const purchases = [];
   const cashback = 0.005;

   const commentForm = document.querySelector('[data-id="purchase-form"]');
   const nameInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="name"]');
   const priceInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="price"]');
   const button = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="price"]');
   const purchasesList = document.querySelector('[data-id="purchases-list"]');
   

   button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (nameInput.value != '' && priceInput.value != '') {
    purchases.push({
      id: nextId++,
      name: nameInput.value,
      price: priceInput.value,
    });
  }
  createElement(nameInput.value);
  nameInput.value = '';
});

function createElement(ci) {
  const newPurchase = document.createElement('li');
  newPurchase.setAttribute('data-comment-id', nextId - 1);
  newPurchase.textContent = `${ci} for sum of ${priceInput.value} $. (cashback- ${cashbackSum})`;
  purchasesList.appendChild(newPurchase);
}

function cashbackSum() {
  return Number(priceInput, 10) * cashback;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <form data-id="purchase-form">
        <input data-input="name" />
        <input data-input="price" />
        <button type="button" data-action="add">Add</button>
      </form>
      <ul data-id="purchases-list"></ul>
      <div>Total cashback is: <span data-id="total cashback"></span></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be a few bugs in the given snippet:

1. You are not getting the value of input box on each click so array is not going to contain the new values. [Make them let instead of const and fetch value on each button click event]
2. CashbackSum function was not being called.
3. Created a function for totalCashback that uses the reduce method of array to get the total cashback sum.

```js
   let nextId = 1;

   const purchases = [];
   const cashback = 0.005;

   const commentForm = document.querySelector('[data-id="purchase-form"]');
   let nameInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="name"]');
   let priceInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="price"]');
   const button = commentForm.querySelector('[data-action="add"]');
   const purchasesList = document.querySelector('[data-id="purchases-list"]');
   const totalCashback = document.querySelector('[data-id="total cashback"]');
   const errorMsg = document.querySelector('[data-id="error"]');

   button.addEventListener('click', () => {
     nameInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="name"]');
     priceInput = commentForm.querySelector('[data-input="price"]');
     if (nameInput.value != '' && priceInput.value != '') {
       purchases.push({
         id: nextId++,
         name: nameInput.value,
         price: priceInput.value,
       });
       createElement(nameInput.value);
       nameInput.value = '';
       errorMsg.textContent = '';
       totalCashback.textContent = calculateTotalCashback() + ' $.';
     }else{
       errorMsg.textContent = 'Please fill both the fields: [name and price]';
     }
   });

   function createElement(ci) {
     const newPurchase = document.createElement('li');
     newPurchase.setAttribute('data-comment-id', nextId - 1);
     newPurchase.textContent = `${ci} for sum of ${priceInput.value} $. (cashback- ${cashbackSum()})`;
     purchasesList.appendChild(newPurchase);
   }

   function cashbackSum() {
     return Number(priceInput.value, 10) * cashback;
   }

    function calculateTotalCashback() {
    return purchases.reduce((sum, item) => {
        return sum + (parseFloat(item.price, 10) * cashback);
    }, 0);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <form data-id="purchase-form">
        <input data-input="name" />
        <input data-input="price" />
        <button type="button" data-action="add">Add</button>
        <br /><span data-id="error"></span>
      </form>
      <ul data-id="purchases-list"></ul>
      <div>Total cashback is: <span data-id="total cashback"></span></div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed , a function for totalCashback with reduce method . I have a better understanding now of using the method